# VB.NET %appdata% path access is denied

Tags: vb.net

I want a folder to be created inside user's %appdata% folder, it does create, but it cannot write a file inside the folder, it says "Access denied", I googled it, but nothing worked for me.

```
Dim SpecialAppData As String = GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
        Dim CLOUDSAVEDFILESCFG As String = SpecialAppData & "\da_dev\clientsettings\cloud\"
        If System.IO.Directory.Exists(SpecialAppData & "\da_dev\clientsettings\cloud\") Then

        Else
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(SpecialAppData & "\da_dev\clientsettings\cloud\")
        End If
        timeout(0.5)
        Dim objWriterCSF As New System.IO.StreamWriter(CLOUDSAVEDFILESCFG)
        TextBox1.Text = My.Settings.username
        TextBox2.Text = My.Settings.password
        If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(SpecialAppData & "\da_dev\clientsettings\cloud\" & "files.cfg") Then

        Else
            objWriterCSF.Write("0")
            objWriterCSF.Close()
        End If
```

The error is:

[image: picture_of_error]

EDIT:

I noticed the picture says that it cannot find path, I fixed that, but now I get the issue:

[image: pic]

Comment: It shows that it cannot find part of that path

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not "open a file" that is actually a directory.

```
Dim CLOUDSAVEDFILESCFG As String = SpecialAppData & "\da_dev\clientsettings\cloud\"
```

`CLOUDSAVEDFILESCFG` points to a directory.

Answer (score 0):

The error here is not that access is denied, but that the directory does not exist. You can use `Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(CLOUDSAVEFILESCFG))` to ensure that the directory exists before trying to create a file within it.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

Forgot to add a file behind CLOUDSAVEDFILESCFG...

Like this:

```
Dim objWriterCSF As New System.IO.StreamWriter(CLOUDSAVEDFILESCFG & "\files.cfg")
```